# How to run VMware 16 on Windows Server 2022 host?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, windows-server

I am trying to run latest VMWare Workstation Pro (16.2.4 build-20089737) on Windows Server 2022 host (21H2).

When I start a VM I got the

> VMWare Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role...

However the Hyper-V role is removed, actually never been there. I started the Turn Windows features on or off (actually the Server Manager) and Hyper-V is unchecked.

Then I actually checked in the Hyper-V role, then restart, then checked off then restart, still, the issue and VMWare error message remains.

**Question**

How can I run VMWare Workstation Pro on Windows Server 2022 host?

Comment: Try in a CMD run as Administrator this command : `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc, many thx, I've already did that, when I wrote to OP, and since then I getting the error message. (Before I got the Device / Credential guard related error message from VMWare, so I followedcthe link and I ran bcdedit...

Comment: @john, many thx, sounds sad, but as we have seen similar false version based messages in the past decades, it has some slight possibility...

Comment: @John: You should put up an answer.

Comment: good being here, getting completely shallow canned comment which costed a few people a time to read, then delete that comment, then force removed my answer comment, then downvoted :-). Good luck for that attitude. Anyway the bright side, that at least two people cared about improving the site, and having good and useful comments, then answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to install VMware Workstation V16 on Server 2022. (I am using VMware Workstation V16 here).

Please see this VMware Community forum article:

[VMware Workstation on Server 2022](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Can-I-run-VMware-Workstation-Pro-16-and-Hyper-V-and-docker-linux/td-p/2868689)

> So I guess technically Server 2022 with Hyper-V can be compatible with
> VMware Workstation, but Server 2022 is not in VMware Workstation's
> compatible list .....   Maybe VMware will fix this later, I hope.